# Combining constraints?

Tags: haskell, constraints, combinators

I'm looking for a way to combine two (or more) constraints such that `Combine c1 c2 a` implies both `c1 a` and `c2 a`, and vice versa. This could be useful when constraints are used as input:

```hs
data HList constraint where
  Empty :: HList constraint
  (:*:) :: constraint a => a -> HList constraint -> HList constraint
```

Where `show` and `negate` could be applied to elements of an hlist typed `HList (Combine Show Num)`.

Having these requirements, `type Combine c1 c2 a = (c1 a, c2 a)` won't do as type synonyms must be saturated. I as well tried declaring `Combine` as a class but couldn't imply that `(Combine c1 c2 a) => c1 a` or `c2 a`:

```hs
class (c1 a, c2 a) => Combine c1 c2 a
instance (c1 a, c2 a) => Combine c1 c2 a
instance Combine c1 c2 a => c1 a  -- error: Illegal head of an instance declaration
instance Combine c1 c2 a => c2 a  -- error: Illegal head of an instance declaration
```

I wonder if this is truly possible, or else what are the good workarounds.

Comment: It seems to me like `Combine` should already be defined somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: It's in [*sop-core* as `And`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-SOP-Constraint.html#t:And).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that `Combine c1 c2 a` implies `c1 a` and `c2 a` is already contained in the declaration

```
class (c1 a, c2 a) => Combine c1 c2 a
```

That's just how superclasses work! This is a feature you've definitely seen before.

```
-- Ord is declared "class Eq a => Ord a", therefore this works
eqOrd :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
eqOrd = (==) -- want Eq a, have Ord a, superclass constraint says this is enough
```

So everything you want `Combine` to do is accomplished by writing simply

```
class (c1 a, c2 a) => Combine c1 c2 a
instance (c1 a, c2 a) => Combine c1 c2 a
```

E.g. the following typechecks

```
unzipCon :: HList (Combine c1 c2) -> (HList c1, HList c2)
unzipCon Empty      = (Empty, Empty)
unzipCon (x :*: xs) = (x :*: xs1, x :*: xs2)
  where (xs1, xs2) = unzipCon xs
```

Comment: Usually call this `(&)`.